# Develop a for loop and use the paste0 command to print the following 26 strings

Tags: r

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H57RP.png)

We use the command

```
sa=paste0("0",c(1:9),"A", collapse="|")
```

to print out

```
"01A|02A|03A|04A|05A|06A|07A|08A|09A"
```

We also use `toupper(letters)` and print out the 26 capital letters.
Develop a for loop and use the paste0 command to print the 26 strings following the pattern above but for each of the 26 letters.

Comment: Try `lapply(LETTERS, \(x) paste0("0", 1:9, x, collapse="|"))`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sa<-c()
for (i in LETTERS) {
  sa<-c(sa,paste0("0",c(1:9),i, collapse="|"))
  
}
```

Comment: `sa={}` is wrong, it should be `sa=c()`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Tried it with both {} and c(). Both the output class is character and there was no difference in the result. Can you please explain what is the difference?

Comment: The difference is idiomatic only. `{}` encloses expressions and since there's nothing there the result is a `NULL` expression; `c()` combines vectors, in this case none and the result is also `NULL`. So my first comment, to call it wrong, is too strong. It's just not usual for the reason I mentioned.

Comment: What about `sa<-character(length(LETTERS))` and `sa[i]<-paste(etc)`? This would create the results vector beforehand instead of extending it in each loop iteration, a memory inefficient and slow operation. Upvote, BTW.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have rectified the same.